# Python connection to Firebird gdb file

Tags: python, firebird, interbase

I want to access a gdb file with python.
I'm new to firebird and interbase.

I can access my file with this command: (Debian 8.4)
isql-fb mydb.gdb

How can I connect to same file with Python?
I tried fdb and kinterbasdb and always get an error message:

I have tried these lines:

```
con = fdb.connect(dsn='/home/bruno/Desktop/mydb.gdb')
con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:/home/bruno/Desktop/mydb.gdb')
con = fdb.connect(dsn='/home/bruno/Desktop/mydb.gdb', user='SYSDBA', password='*****')
```

The error is always something like:

```
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.', -902, 335544472)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: are you sure the `user` and `password` in the third try were correct?

Comment: Yeah, it's correct.
I can access the original file just without user and password.
The gdb file was not made on my pc, I just get it to work on it.

Comment: Which Firebird version? Note that the username and password are required when connecting through Firebird server; leaving it out is only an option when using Firebird 3 embedded, so your first two connection strings are likely not valid. Also note that when connecting through the server, that the server needs access to the location of the database file.

Comment: Finally, Firebird and Interbase are not the same. Firebird was forked from Interbase in 2000, and although there are similarities, they are **not the same**, and databases cannot be shared between Firebird and Interbase.

Comment: The only way that I can use SELECT command is:
sudo isql-fb mydb.gdb

Without sudo doesn't work.
I have to make this query using python.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your time.
I solved it changing sysdba password with gsec.
The password was ok in config file but not in security database.